# flexunit on jenkins server --- ant unable to build without error

Tags: apache-flex, jenkins, ant, flexunit

I have already installed vncserver, flex sdk 4.6 and xvnc plugin in my jenkins.

Not sure what else i need to do.

This is my last build error message from jenkins

```
Building in workspace <http://example.com:8080/job/flexproject%20develop/ws/>
Checkout:flexproject develop / <http://example.com:8080/job/flexproject%20develop/ws/> - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@78da5318
Using strategy: Default
Last Built Revision: Revision 6eca1f87e583b1b7a99825ff075f2e4e4f3b87ea (origin/develop)
Fetching changes from 1 remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from git@github.com:simkimsia/STORYBOT.git
Commencing build of Revision 6eca1f87e583b1b7a99825ff075f2e4e4f3b87ea (origin/develop)
Checking out Revision 6eca1f87e583b1b7a99825ff075f2e4e4f3b87ea (origin/develop)
Starting xvnc
[flexproject develop] $ vncserver :16

New 'web1:16 (jenkins)' desktop is web1:16

Starting applications specified in /var/lib/jenkins/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /var/lib/jenkins/.vnc/web1:16.log

[flexproject develop] $ ant
Buildfile: <http://example.com:8080/job/flexproject%20develop/ws/build.xml>
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource flexTasks.tasks. It could not be found.

clean-all:
   [delete] Deleting <http://example.com:8080/job/flexproject%20develop/ws/build/output/unit/generated-flexunit-config.xml>
   [delete] Deleting <http://example.com:8080/job/flexproject%20develop/ws/build/output/unit>
   [delete] Deleting <http://example.com:8080/job/flexproject%20develop/ws/build/output/report/flexunit>
   [delete] Deleting <http://example.com:8080/job/flexproject%20develop/ws/build/output/report>

clean:
     [echo] Storybot :: clean finished.

test-air:
     [copy] Copying 1 file to <http://example.com:8080/job/flexproject%20develop/ws/build/output/unit>
     [echo] run-flexunit :: setting FLEX_HOME to ${env.FLEX_HOME}
    [mkdir] Created dir: <http://example.com:8080/job/flexproject%20develop/ws/build/output/report/flexunit>

BUILD FAILED
<http://example.com:8080/job/flexproject%20develop/ws/buildsupport/target/test-air.xml>:4: The following error occurred while executing this line:
<http://example.com:8080/job/flexproject%20develop/ws/buildsupport/base/base-macros.xml>:212: The following error occurred while executing this line:
<http://example.com:8080/job/flexproject%20develop/ws/buildsupport/base/base-macros.xml>:174: Please specify, or verify the location for, the FLEX_HOME property.  It is required when testing with 'air' as the player or when using the 'testSource' element.  It should point to the installation directory for a Flex SDK.

Total time: 2 seconds
Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure
Terminating xvnc.
$ vncserver -kill :16
Killing Xvnc4 process ID 28784
Recording test results
```

inside my workspace project, i ran ant build.xml

i get

```
jenkins@web1:~/workspace/flexproject$ ant build.xml
Buildfile: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/flexproject/build.xml
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource flexTasks.tasks. It could not be found.

BUILD FAILED
Target "build.xml" does not exist in the project "flexproject". 

Total time: 2 seconds
```

int he same folder when i run ant

i get

```
Buildfile: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/flexproject/build.xml
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource flexTasks.tasks. It could not be found.

clean-all:
   [delete] Deleting /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/flexproject/build/output/unit/generated-flexunit-config.xml
   [delete] Deleting /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/flexproject/build/output/unit
   [delete] Deleting /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/flexproject/build/output/report/flexunit
   [delete] Deleting /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/flexproject/build/output/report

clean:
     [echo] Storybot :: clean finished.

test-air:
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/flexproject/build/output/unit
     [echo] run-flexunit :: setting FLEX_HOME to /opt/flex
    [mkdir] Created dir: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/flexproject/build/output/report/flexunit

BUILD FAILED
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/flexproject/buildsupport/target/test-air.xml:4: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/flexproject/buildsupport/base/base-macros.xml:212: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/flexproject/buildsupport/base/base-macros.xml:174: Could not create test runner from template.
```

Please advise.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Could not load definitions from resource flexTasks.task
```

hints that you missed to set the path to your `flex4.6` directory (`lib/*.jar` inside) correctly.